# Workaround for set rating in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, parse-platform, google-maps-markers, marker

I am trying to set the rating of a rating bar inside of a marker's content window, but whenever I try setting the rating from the class which contains the fragment, the rating doesn't change.  I have tried inflating a view (see below code) but that doesn't work.  Is there another way to work around this? One possible problem is the implementation of the Parse, but I can't seem to

Thanks,

Jacob

Here is my java:

```
query.whereContains("review", titleRev);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {

                            for (ParseObject parseObj : scoreList) {
                                int x = 0;

                                String ratingNum = parseObj.get("rating").toString();
                                float ratingNumF = Float.valueOf(ratingNum);
                                myList.add(x, ratingNumF);

                                x++;
                            }

                            float sum = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                                sum += myList.get(i);
                            }


                            if (sum > 0) {
                                final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();

                                final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.windowlayout, null);

                                RatingBar ra = (RatingBar) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.windowRatingBar);
                                ra.setRating(1f);




                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(FindOpp.this, "Sorry, this organization has no reviews", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually ended up fixing this problem by getting a reference to all of my markers on the Google map and then adding the ratings to a string set which correlated with the marker.getTitle(), and I average the results in the getInfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the parse query which is running in the background thread, but not the callback that pushes the results back on to the UI thread.

The correct way of implementing this is to correctly set the data that is going to inflate the custom layout. For that I would suggest to replace the default into window, override getInfoWindow(Marker) with your custom rendering and place the ratings data in that customInfoWindow. It would be more helpful if you can share that part of code or make changes in the existing code. But the former is a better option to implement this functionality.

Comment: I understand what your saying in creating a customInfoWindow, but could you possibly elaborate on how I can do that (codewise)?